# Content-Type text/plain being ignored in IE based on file extension

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, content-type

I have a classic ASP page that is setting the ContentType to "text/plain" and streaming the bytes of a text file to the browser. However, Internet Explorer 7 (and presumably other versions) is ignoring this and instead of opening the darn text document in a monospaced font as it should it's prompting "Do you want to save or open this file?" because it's coming from a web page ending in ".asp".

When I set .txt files to be run through the ASP parser and then make a copy of my .asp page with the extension .txt, everything works fine.

I've examined the headers in Firebug on FF and know I'm setting the content-type correctly and not missing any other important headers.

Is there any other technique to preventing IE from using the file extension to change how it responds?

This is nonsense! Respect my content-type, you third-rate browser!

Comment: Refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329661

Comment: @Beemer, I did find that article before asking my question when I was searching to figure the problem out. Did you notice that it just confirms IE has this problem? The article doesn't give any way to fix it except for providing content that helps IE's content sniffing, which is impossible with a text document that has no structure. So that link is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the filename (with extension) using the content disposition header

Something like Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="File.txt")
And you already said the content type header is being set correctly so that should do it.

Comment: It's funny, I did searches for "Content-Disposition" before asking this question and came up with really slim pickings on how to use it. Most of the content online is telling how to force a Save As dialog, not how to prevent it.

Comment: Well, you can try      http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt   ... or   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519    ... or something like http://www.asp101.com/samples/viewasp.asp?file=download_sample.asp .... its basically a header just like your content type, I use content disposition all the time with php to do things like save generated data into .csv files or log files.

Comment: This was a perfect fix to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You know what the funny thing is? I eventually switched to a very plain html page with the text inside a <pre> block. This let me add some javascript to the page to prevent right-clicking, selecting, and copying.